# Can't find stylesheet to import. Angular 17

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

i'm trying to import angular material theming in the styles.scss file, But when i run ng serve, it throws the "Can't find stylesheet to import." Error.

Below is my import

```
@import '@angular/material/theming';
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F04cW.png)
I'm currently using Angular cli 17.

I've tried importing using the @use, but the error was the same. And i tried to change the path of the import to the node_module/@angular/material/theming.

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant tags. [tag:angularjs] is (as the tag information says) about AngularJS v1.9 and less. [tag:angular] is a different framework, and exists for versions 2 and above.

Comment: Also, [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Didn't know that, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `@import '~@angular/material/theming';`
Refer [this link](https://v7.material.angular.io/guide/theming)

Comment: no difference with this change

Answer (score 2):

No need for
`@import '@angular/material/theming';
in Angular 17 any more.
See official documentation [here](https://v17.material.angular.io/guide/theming)